# Function return first index meets condition

Tags: python, indexing, conditional-statements

My function doesn't stop when the first time the condition is met (the lowest value in list started when started at start_index). What do I have to add to achieve it.
My code is:

```
def index_min(l, start_index):
    min_ele = l[start_index]
    idx = []
    for i in range(start_index, len(l)):
        if l[i] <= min_ele:
            min_ele = l[i]
            idx = i
    return idx

print(index_of_min([10, 7, 19, 16, 5, 10, 5, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 12, 8, 9, 18, 1, 10, 7, 18],6))
```

It returns index 18 instead of index 7
start index is 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant to call `index_min()` in the `print()` statement.

If you're looking to get the first appearance of the smallest number, you can change the `<=` to a `<`:

```py
def index_min(l, start_index):
    min_ele = l[start_index]
    idx = []
    for i in range(start_index, len(l)):
        # If we see a value equal to the minimum seen so far, don't update the index.
        if l[i] < min_ele:
            min_ele = l[i]
            idx = i
    return idx

print(index_min([10, 7, 19, 16, 5, 10, 5, 1, 5, 4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 12, 8, 9, 18, 1, 10, 7, 18],6))
```

Comment: I would like to do it without built in functions. Otherwise it would be easy.

Comment: What constitutes built-in functions? Do you mean `range()` and `len()`?

Comment: I think they confused `index_min` (their own function) for the built-in `min` function that they're presumably not allowed to use.

Comment: It's because they're doing a school assignment that's making them reimplement basic functions as a way to learn about loops etc.

Comment: Eh, I'm hesitant to criticize the OP for that. This is probably some sort of assignment, and the prohibition on "built-ins" is likely some requirement of that. I blame the person who wrote that spec moreso than the OP.